# How do I set open_basedir in .htaccess? (shared hosting)

Tags: php, .htaccess, open-basedir

I have this function on my website where users can create files/edit/delete them, etc. When they make a file, it goes to "www.example.com/site/(their username)/file.php". But, with php they can potentially access files outside of their directory, and I want to limit that with a user-accessible .htaccess file. I have seen I can set open_basedir in .htaccess, but haven't found anything on HOW to set it. I have seen `php_value open_basedir "/directory/subdirectory"`, but when I try it on a file it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running PHP? Module? CGI? What value is returned when reading this value from a file accessed within this location?

Comment: Don't know how I'm running PHP, using shared hosting. I'm using a `$cont=file_get_contents("index.php");
echo "<textarea>".$cont."</textarea>";`
to check if it works, and all it displays is the textarea with the file contents.

Comment: You can call `phpinfo()` to see how PHP is being run. Basically, you need to be running PHP as an Apache module to be able to set this in .htaccess, otherwise if you're on FastCGI you'll need to use a `.user.ini` (or per-directory `php.ini`?) file.

Comment: OK, I called `phpinfo()`. What shows how I'm running PHP?

Comment: "Server API" - near the top. Also what version of PHP?

Comment: LiteSpeed V6.8, PHP version 5.2.17 (for some functional reasons)

Comment: Ah, your PHP version appears to be a problem unfortunately... you need PHP 5.3+ to be able to further restrict `open_basedir` at runtime.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you have any suggestions on how I could restrict it?

Comment: Just the usual file perms. Only make editable (by PHP) what needs to be editable. Make sure that user editable content is quite separate from any of your core files.

Comment: I have many files, is it possible for me to change permission for all files at the same time?

Comment: I wish this question had been answered as asked. I'm having trouble writing a file into a full rwx directory with NO basedir according to phpinfo.

Answer (score 1):

in a root page like index, execute the PHP command `echo __DIR__`
put the result folder in your htaccess like `php_value open_basedir "result"`.

Check it in any page with PHP command `phpinfo()`